# MySQL Active Record problem

Tags: mysql, activerecord, codeigniter

I'm using MySQL ActiveRecord with CodeIgniter to submit queries, but have run into some snags when using the "select" function.  For instance, this MySQL query works perfectly within phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT review_id, firms_name
FROM reviews AS r
JOIN firms AS f ON f.firms_id = r.review_target_id
WHERE r.review_id =3
ORDER BY r.review_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It gives me two columns, exactly what I need.

However, this only gives me one column, "review_id":

```
$this->db->select('review_id', 'firms_name');
$this->db->from('reviews as r');
$this->db->join('firms as f', 'f.firms_id = r.review_target_id');
$this->db->where('r.review_id', $id);
$this->db->order_by('r.review_timestamp', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

If I delete the 'select' clause, I get all the information I need, but would like to understand what I'm doing wrong and how I can reduce the load on my db.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('review_id', 'firms_name');
```

should be written like this (the column names should be a single string):

```
$this->db->select('review_id, firms_name');
```

Also, remember that you can always use `$this->db->last_query();` to output the last query that was run, so you can see the exact SQL statement being executed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  As always, if I were more careful, I wouldn't have these problems to begin with.  Many thanks.